# can we feed tf.variable to tf.placeholder in feed_dict?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to do a simple task with tensorflow. but i am geting one error

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fv = tf.Variable(10.0,name="first_var")

sv = tf.Variable(20.0,np.random.randn(),name="second_var")

fvp = tf.placeholder("float32",name="first_fvp",shape=[])

svp = tf.placeholder("float32",name="second_svp",shape=[])

result = tf.Variable(0.0,name="output")

result =  np.multiply(fvp,svp)

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

print(sess.run(result,feed_dict={fvp:fv,svp:sv}))
```

error = setting an array element with a sequence.

In this case, I am getting an error

and if I use

```
print(sess.run(result,feed_dict={fvp:5.0,svp:10.0}))
```

I am getting output 50.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I still don't quite understand what is your question is. It seems that you've solved that error already. Please edit if possible.

### About that error:

You can not feed Tensor(s) into that `feed_dict`.

Read `tensorflow/python/client/session.py` carefully. When you feed some data to `feed_dict={}`, Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles. In your case, the `fv` and `sv` are tensors.

So the second of yours `print(sess.run(result,feed_dict={fvp:5.0,svp:10.0}))` will work.

you can also try `fv = np.array([10.0])`, `sv = np.array([20.0])`

Also, you dont need this `result = tf.Variable(0.0,name="output")`, if you want to name the output, you can use `result =  tf.identity(np.multiply(fvp,svp), name="output")`

Comment: thank you very much... my question was that only. what things can I pass into feed_dict{}? and now I get it. We can use Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles for feeding feed_dict{}. can't pass tf.Variable() CZ they are tensor :)